# Filter and sort a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
[{
    "number": "4",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 6.4
    }
}, {
    "number": "3",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 5.4
    }
}, {
    "number": "4",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 5.4
    }
}]
```

I am trying to create a new array with the following criteria:

1. Get highest rating (`array.rating.average`) of each number (`array.number`)

Output should be:

```
[{
    "number": "4",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 6.4
    }
}, {
    "number": "3",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 5.4
    }
}
}]
```

I have just managed to sort by highest rating:

```
array.sort(function(a , b) {
    return a.rating.average - b.rating.average;
});
array.reverse();
```

But, now, I just only want one object per duplicate `array.number`, keeping the one that has the highest `array.rating.average`.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: Since 3 and 4 have the same average rating. Any reason why number 3 is chosen over 4?

Comment: @SamuelToh I would like to have an array with each of the highest rating "number".

Comment: @westefan I have already gone through those 2 urls already, and both of them have different outcomes to what I am trying to do.

Comment: Check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) then sort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.number === b.number) {
    // If two elements have same number, then the one who has larger rating.average wins
    return b.rating.average - a.rating.average;
  } else {
    // If two elements have different number, then the one who has larger number wins
    return b.number - a.number;
  }
});


array = array.filter((element, index) => {
  return index === 0 || element.number !== array[index-1].number;
});
```

For your test case,

```
[{
  "number": "4",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 6.4
  }
}, {
  "number": "3",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 5.4
  }
}, {
  "number": "4",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 5.4
  }
}]
```

After sorting, the output would be

```
[{
  "number": "4",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 6.4
  }
}, {
  "number": "4",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 5.4
  }
}, {
  "number": "3",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 5.4
  }
}]
```

And after filter, the final result:

```
[{
  "number": "4",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 6.4
  }
}, {
  "number": "3",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 5.4
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you create a dictionary for keeping the highest rating for each number:

```js
var data = [{
    "number": "4",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 6.4
    }
}, {
    "number": "3",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 5.4
    }
}, {
    "number": "4",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 5.4
    }
}];


var filterMap = {};
data.forEach(function (item) {
  if (!filterMap[item.number] || filterMap[item.number].rating.average < item.rating.average) {
    filterMap[item.number] = item;
  }
})

var result = [];

for (var number in filterMap) {
  result.push(filterMap[number]);
}


result.sort(function(a , b) {
   return b.rating.average - a.rating.average;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr = [{
    "number": "4",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 6.4
    }
}, {
    "number": "3",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 5.4
    }
}, {
    "number": "4",
    "fileName": "fileXX",
    "rating": {
        "average": 5.4
    }
}]

arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){return b.number-a.number || b.rating.average-a.rating.average}).filter(function(a,b,c){return !b || c[b-1].number != a.number});
console.log(arr);
```

I believe that this will solve your problem by sorting and filtering.

EDIT: Should now support older browsers.

Comment: Sort functions need to return -1, 0, or 1, not a boolean.

Comment: @tor A boolean evaluates to `true` or `false`, 1 and 0, therefore I do not see a problem. Additionally, it works, and is essentially the same as the answers after it.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `sort` and the function to be passed to it. Returning the equivalent of 0 and 1 does work in some cases, but it does not work reliably.

Comment: @tor on both the http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort sources, it has absolutely no mention of undefined behavior with booleans. When evaluating, it will check if `true > 0`, which will always return `true`.

Comment: Educate yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Comment: @tor Thank you, I see the issue now. I had only been using Chrome, and so I never noticed this does not work on IE or old versions of Opera. I will attempt to fix it right now.

Comment: @tor It seems to be working properly now. Does it seem alright to you?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use lodash method for sort by anything that you want to sort by fileName, number, etc.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

var data = [{
  "number": "4",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 6.4
  }
}, {
  "number": "3",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 5.4
  }
}, {
  "number": "4",
  "fileName": "fileXX",
  "rating": {
    "average": 5.4
  }
}]

var result = _.sortBy(data, ['number']);

console.log(result)

Output:
[ { number: '3', fileName: 'fileXX', rating: { average: 5.4 } },
  { number: '4', fileName: 'fileXX', rating: { average: 6.4 } },
  { number: '4', fileName: 'fileXX', rating: { average: 5.4 } } ]
```

Comment: The OP's desired output includes filtering out duplicates, which is missing.