# Sort and manipulate array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array:

var curr =     [{
      "Year": 2019,
      "Title": "Asset Management Sample",
      "Sum": 1020000.0,
      "Budget":0

```
}, {
  "Year": 2019,
  "Title": "Monday test 2",
  "Sum": 2546658.0,
  "Budget":100
}, {
  "Year": 2020,
  "Title": "Asset Management Sample",
  "Sum": 1020000.0,
  "Budget":1000
}, {
  "Year": 2020,
  "Title": "Monday test 2",
  "Sum": 3472000.0,
  "Budget":100
}, {
  "Year": 2021,
  "Title": "Asset Management Sample",
  "Sum": 1020000.0,
  "Budget":100
}, {
  "Year": 2021,
  "Title": "Monday test 2",
  "Sum": 2452000.0,
  "Budget":100
}]
```

That I need to change to:

```
[{
  "Year": 2019,
  "Asset Management Sample": 1020000.0,
  "Monday test": 2546658.0
}, {
  "Year": 2020,
  "Asset Management Sample": 1020000.0,
  "Monday test 2": 3472000.0
}, {
  "Year": 2021,
  "Asset Management Sample": 1020000.0,
  "Monday test 2": 2452000.0
}]
```

With help from earlier posters I have used .reduce (slightly modified from below) to generate this:

```
      var res = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
      acc[curr.Year] = acc[curr.Year];
      acc[curr.Year] = acc[curr.Year] || { Year: curr.Year } ;
      acc[curr.Year][curr.Title] = curr.Sum;

      return acc;
```

I need to expand this to include a sum of all the budget values for each year (there should be a single budget value per year). I added the following line in before the return:

```
acc[curr.Year][curr.Budget] = curr[curr.Budget] || { Budget: curr.Budget } ;
```

It is adding individual entries for each Budget value. How do I sum the Budget values and return it without affecting the other returned array?

Comment: Please show your code. Also, there is no `groupBy` in JavaScript.

Comment: Check for answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302871/filter-and-sort-a-javascript-array

Comment: Please edit your question and show the current code.

Comment: You want to group by `year` or `title`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` like so:

```js
const arr = [{"Year":2019,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2019,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":2546658},{"Year":2020,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2020,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":3472000},{"Year":2021,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2021,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":2452000}];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, { Year, Title, Sum }) => (acc[Year] = acc[Year] || { Year }, acc[Year][Title] = Sum, acc), {}));
console.log(res);
```

More verbose version:

```js
const arr = [{"Year":2019,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2019,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":2546658},{"Year":2020,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2020,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":3472000},{"Year":2021,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2021,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":2452000}];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, { Year, Title, Sum }) => {
  acc[Year] = acc[Year] || { Year };
  acc[Year][Title] = Sum;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var arr = [{"Year":2019,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2019,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":2546658},{"Year":2020,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2020,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":3472000},{"Year":2021,"Title":"Asset Management Sample","Sum":1020000},{"Year":2021,"Title":"Monday test 2","Sum":2452000}];
var res = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc[curr.Year] = acc[curr.Year] || { Year: curr.Year };
  acc[curr.Year][curr.Title] = curr.Sum;
  return acc;
}, {});
res = Object.keys(res).map(function(key) {
  return res[key];
});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: It's okay to use semicolons, new lines and `return`. This is not code-golf :) It'll be very hard for the OP to understand what's going on here

Comment: My bad @adiga :) I'll add a more verbose version.

Comment: Edited @adiga is that understandable :D

Comment: `Object.values()` is ES2016+ (Not even 2015)

Comment: Welp, missed that.

Comment: The ES5 syntax worked perfectly, the reduce version gave me an error, is that due to the platform I am working on?

Comment: Most likely @Mondo - it's working for me in the above snippet.